# Type-cast overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, typecast-operator

I need to throw an exception whe I do such typecast: `(B*)a`where a is a pointer to object of a base class A and B is a derived class.

```
class A
{
    protected:
        int a;
    public:
        operator B*()
        {
            throw(1);
        }

};

class B: public A
{
 protected:
    int b;
};

void main()
{
    A *a;
    (B*)a;
}
```

I try overloading, but it doesn't work with a pointer to A just works with an object. How to overload this operation to make it work with a pointer to my base class?

Comment: Sry for my poor English,I tried in Russian version of stackoverflow,but haven`t foud an answer

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Regardless, you really cannot as `a` is an `A*`, not an `A`, and you cannot overload `A*`'s `operator B*`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo my task is to throw an exception when I do typecast for this.Class B has to be derived and class A has to be a base class.There wasn`t mentioned that I has to use overloading,but I thought It can work.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Also tried dynamic cast,but it seems not to generate an exception for pointers,only for links

Comment: The `operator B *()` converts an object of type `A` into a `B *`.  It doesn't convert an `A*` to a `B*`.   There is no way to do the latter with operator overloading   (pointers do not have member functions).

Comment: This question also strikes me as an example of the XY problem.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Peter how to do it in another way?Can it work with converting constructor?

Comment: No.   Only struct/class types have constructors.   Pointers do not.

Comment: No, there is no way to change the behavior of a cast from `A*` to `B*`.

Comment: Implicit conversion from an `A*` to a `B*` won't compile anyway.    Making it succeed, and just throwing an exception (i.e. effectively turning a compile-time error into a runtime error) is a step backward anyway.

Comment: @Peter Im pretty sure it will compile,I`ve just tested it.Im using gcc compiler.

Comment: You missed my point.  An IMPLICIT type conversion will not compile.   An explicit conversion will.   Try `B *bb = a` or [equivalently] `B *bb(a)` in your code.     But `B *bb = (B *)a` will compile - a key property of an explicit type conversion is that it forces the compiler to do a conversion it would otherwise refuse to do - which is why explicit conversions are often considered poor practice, even if they are needed sometimes.     But it is still not possible to overload such a conversion, whether it is implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a custom converter only for a class, not for a pointer. But you can create a class that mimics a pointer (that's the way *smart pointers* work).

Here is an example of such a class:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    int a;
public:
    int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    virtual ~A() {}  // intended to be derived
};

class B;  // forward declaration

class Astar { // mimics a A*
private:
    A* pa;
public:
    Astar(A* p): pa(p) {}
    A* operator ->() {
        return pa;
    }
    operator B* ();  // declare the custom conversion operator
    A& operator *() {
        return *pa;
    }
};

class B: public A
{
protected:
    int b;
public:
    B(int a, int b): b(b) {
        A::a = a;
    }
    int getB() {
        return b;
    }
};

Astar::operator B*() {            // defines the custom conversion
    return dynamic_cast<B *>(pa);
}

int main()
{
    B b(1,2);
    Astar x(&b);       // x acts exactly as a A* would:
    std::cout << x->getA() << " - " << (*x).getA() << std::endl;

    B* pb = x;         // conversion to a plain B* is automatic
    std::cout << pb->getB() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles without a warning and output is *as expected*...